# external measurement connection to qgis experimental

Tags: qfield, qgis-android

Recently I used QGIS experimental (for Android). I need a direct connection from a mobile or tablet measurement device to QGIS experimental. I added external resources field for feature photo which is expected to be taken directly on the field by a mobile camera and located via GPS. Is this possible in QGIS experimental (not Qfield)?